# Change of variables for sumations.

Tags: summation

I'd like to know a method to do a change of variables for sumations; as far as I am concerned it should be analogous to change of variables when integrating a continuous function.
I got this summation:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=-\infty}^n 2^k\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-k} =\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} 2^{n-r}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{r}
\end{equation}
I started with the left side and got to the right one by mere intuition but when writing down my relations $r=n-k$, I just can't find a way to do it algebraically; I suspect I'm missing some important property but this is like the $3^{\text{rd}}$ time I've try to understand this, so I'd really appreciate some extra help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By $n-k=r$ we obtain

$$\sum_{k=-N}^n 2^k\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-k} = \sum_{r=n+N}^0 2^{n-r}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{r} =\sum_{r=0}^{n+N} 2^{n-r}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{r}$$

and taking the limit as $N\to \infty$ we obtain the identity.